# Spring Data Rest - Custom LinkRelationProvider is never used

Tags: spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

I am creating a service based on spring-boot-starter-parent 2.6.1 and use spring data rest to expose my JPA repository:

```
public interface PointRepo extends CrudRepository<Point<?>, String> {}
```

The `Point` type has subtypes `Quantity` and `Switch`, so a `GET /points` currently returns something like:

```
{
  "_embedded" : {
    "switches" : [ {
      ...
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/switch/office_light"
        },
        ...
      }
    }],
    "quantities" : [ {
      ...
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/quantity/office_temp"
        },
        ...
      }
    }
```

Since I am not planning to expose endpoints `/switches` and `/quantities`, I want all `Point`s to be in `_embedded.points` and the self hrefs to point to `/points`, too. I figured, I need a custom `LinkRelationProvider` so I created this:

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class PointRelProvider extends EvoInflectorLinkRelationProvider {
    
    @Override
    public LinkRelation getCollectionResourceRelFor(final Class<?> type) {
        return super.getCollectionResourceRelFor(Point.class);
    }

    @Override
    public LinkRelation getItemResourceRelFor(Class<?> type) {
        return super.getItemResourceRelFor(Point.class);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(LookupContext delimiter) {
        return Point.class.isAssignableFrom(delimiter.getType());
    }

}
```

I found out the bean gets created, but it has no effect on the output whatsoever. I put breakpoints into each method put none of them ever gets called. Any ideas why that might be the case?

Comment: Have you tried to add a RepositoryRestConfigurer, override configureRepositoryRestConfiguration and setLinkRelationProvider() on RepositoryRestConfiguration?

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to work for me, at least to the point where my breakpoints are getting hit:

```java
@Configuration
public class RestConfiguration extends RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config, CorsRegistry cors) {
         config.setLinkRelationProvider(new DelegatingLinkRelationProvider(
            new PointRelProvider(),
            // the default Spring Data REST link relation provider as a fallback
            new AnnotationLinkRelationProvider(),
            new EvoInflectorLinkRelationProvider()
        ));
    }
}
```

With this, no need to also extend `EvoInflectorLinkRelationProvider` in `PointRelProvider`. You can instead just implement `LinkRelationProvider`.

The `@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)` annotation on `PointRelProvider` is still needed, since `DelegatingLinkRelationProvider` uses these annotations (through `PluginRegistry` → `OrderAwarePluginRegistry.DEFAULT_COMPARATOR` → `AnnotationAwareOrderComparator`) to determine the order in which to sort the providers.